# Using CSS clip-path only affects first object in webkit browsers?

Tags: svg, webkit, clipping

I am trying to use the CSS clip-path attribute to apply an SVG clip-path to some elements in a page. For example, HTML (note that clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" allows the circle to be expressed in fractions of the containing element size):

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.circle:first div').addClass('clipped');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.circle:nth-of-type(2) div').addClass('clipped');
    }, 2000);    
}, 2000);
```

```css
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.circle div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

.clipped {
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#circle_clip);
    -moz-clip-path: url(#circle_clip);
    -o-clip-path: url(#circle_clip);
    clip-path: url(#circle_clip);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="circle">
    <div></div>
</div>

<svg>
    <defs>
        <clippath id="circle_clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".5" />
        </clippath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Using this code, the first element appears properly clipped into a circle, but the second element disappears in Chrome and Safari. On Firefox two elements appear, both properly clipped.

[Here's another Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtjhax/Lkcu8/3/) that actually gets it to work by applying the clipping to each element, removing it from the first before applying to the second, then turning the first back on. Interesting, with timers to "animate" it everything works. If you simply add and remove the classes in a single operation it does not work, as if there was a race condition involved or it needs to finish rendering before the fix takes effect.

Am I doing something wrong or do Webkit browsers have a bug? Can someone get these Fiddles to work?

Comment: Which versions of Chrome and Safari? It might be https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=349701 (fixed in Chrome 35 and up). The fiddles both work fine for me in Opera 25.0.1578.0 and Chrome 38.0.2107.3 dev.

Comment: Thanks Erik. My bad not mentioning browser versions: latest OS X Chrome 36.0.1985.125 and latest OS X Safari 7.0.5 (9537.77.4). Based on what you are saying, it seems possible that it may already be fixed on other operating systems. Investigating.

Comment: Strange, I have the same error but only in Safari and old, WebKit-based Chrome versions.

Comment: @mtjhax What was the solution to this? I'm stuck with this issue.

Comment: @AgniScribe apparently this is due to browser bugs -- it was fixed in Chrome and Firefox for OS X at some point, but still fails on the latest Safari. I tried quite a few workarounds with no luck -- the only thing that made one circle not disappear was adding in timeouts.

Comment: @mtjhax - strange, it works on the Chrome browser when I'm running it through jsfiddle, but not when I'm running from the localhost. thanks for replying.