# Clip-paths working only on first object; causes others to disappear

Tags: css, clip-path

***NOTE***: This is the [**same issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100733/using-css-clip-path-only-affects-first-object-in-webkit-browsers) raised by a previous user (however there was no resolution to the issue).

When applying clip-paths to an image on my webpage running on Chrome from localhost, it works only on the first object. The remaining images (objects) disappear altogether. **However, the same code works just fine when running through [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxz7g740/3/).** Here is the CSS:

```
.art1 > .pic1{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  float: left;
  shape-margin: 4px;
  shape-outside: circle(40% at 50% 50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(40% at 50% 50%);
  margin-left: -1em; 
}

 .art2 > .pic2{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  float: left;
  shape-margin: 4px;
  shape-outside: circle(40% at 50% 50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(40% at 50% 50%);
  margin-left: -1em; 

}

.art3  > .pic3{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  float: left;  
   shape-margin: 4px;
  shape-outside: circle(40% at 50% 50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(40% at 50% 50%);
  margin-left: -1em; 
}
```

This [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cxz7g740/) is a demo of the issue using the exact same code used on my webpage. It shows three identical divs, and the circle clip-path oworks on all 4 images. I had asked the the original submitter what his assessment was: "this is due to browser bugs -- it was fixed in Chrome and Firefox for OS X at some point."

Yet, I have the latest version of Chrome and it's giving that issue when running from my localhost. Is there some way I can get around this?

Comment: Has anyone found a fix to this bug? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this jfiddle again on Chrome, Firefox and IE on my system it gave the same issue, when I tried on the chrome in my mobile, it worked. My conclusion is that, the issue likely arises because of the OS - I'm running Windows 7 on my laptop.